# Restrict Access of files stored on /data folder in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, acl

I have my data (including pdf and images) stored on the /data folder in the root folder. I access these files through one of the actions (i.e. /index/view/path/to/file/in/data/folder).

Are these files searchable on Google? I want to now use ACL to limit access to /index/view, and so hopefully only allow people with certain permissions to view these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bot is visiting links that finds on you site. If nothing is heads to these files, it should not be indexed by Google. But for sure you should make some check if user which requests file have permissions for it.

You can configure ACL that only authenticated user can access index action from your controller. But if some files should be public, then check must take place in Controller.

Comment: Yes, my plan is to restrict access to /index/view/. Another way for me to ask that question is, if there is a way to access the /data folder through the URL directly?

Comment: If you set up your `DocumentRoot` to `public` folder then no.